# Where are Drupal {{page.variable}} variables defined?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal (8) and inherited a Drupal project.

In my page--front.html.twig file i have various `{{page.variable}}`variables. Where is this list of variables defined? I have my "regions" defined in myproject.info.yml. I created new views and blocks for this. Can anyone help out? Thanks in advance

Comment: adding or modifying variables in a theme generally done in a [preprocess hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.3.x). Atleast that was the case in D7, I'm pretty sure it is the same in D8

Comment: You Can use hooks to defined the variables like 1.hook_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) ,2. hook_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables)